# how to store the alphanumeric value in integer type in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, rdbms

I need to store the id of the person in Database.But the id should contain one alpha in beginning for that ,I have followed following thing ,

for id column I set the default value like

```
create table alphanumeric (id int default ('f'||nextval('seq_test'))::int) ;
```

So now table was created like

```
default (('f'::text || nextval('seq_test'::regclass)))::integer
```

After creating the table I insert the values its showing the error like

```
INSERT INTO alpha VALUES (default) ;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "f50"
```

I understood the error but I need this type of storing .....!

Notes : I don't want to use function or triggers .

Comment: You're casting it to `int` but it's `text`. You can't do that. Remove `::integer` from your `DEFAULT`.

Comment: If i take out the typecast integer ,On creating it self its saying error **ERROR:  column "id" is of type integer but default expression is of type text
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a string for your `id`s so use a text column for your `id`:

```
create table alphanumeric (
    id text default ('f' || nextval('seq_test'))
)
```

If you're only use `seq_test` for that column then you probably want it to be [owned by that column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html):

```
alter sequence seq_test owned by alphanumeric.id
```

That way the sequence will be dropped if you drop the table and you won't have an unused sequence cluttering up your database.

One thing you might want to note about this `id` scheme is that they won't sort the way a human would sort them; `'f100' < 'f2'`, for example, will be true and that might have side effects that you'll need to work around.

Comment: Whether is it possible to store the 'f2' in integer type

Comment: You can't do that. Period. You cannot store 'f2' as an integer, because it isn't an integer. You can't store a car in a breadbox. You can't store an ice cube in a furnace. You can't store a wounded sheep in a wolf's den. You can't store 'f2' in an integer.

Comment: @DanielLyons: I can too store a [car](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinky_car) in a breadbox.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes but you have to cast it. ;)

Comment: @muistooshort Bingo! This is fun.

Comment: @DanielLyons: for such an emphatic answer/comment

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a couple more cents to @muistooshort's answer. If you are certain the IDs you want will always conform to a certain regular expression, you can enforce that with a `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE alphanumeric (
  id VARCHAR DEFAULT ('f' || nextval('seqtest') PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  CHECK(id ~ '^[A-Za-z][0-9]+')
);
```

Of course, I'm making a gross assumption about the nature of your identifiers, you will have to apply your own judgement about whether or not your identifiers constitute a regular language.

Secondly, the sort order @muistooshort is talking about is sometimes (confusingly) called 'natural sort' and [you can get a PostgreSQL function to assist with this](http://2kan.tumblr.com/post/361326656/postgres-natural-ordering).